# passing the value stored in a buttons "value property" to my controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to pass the value stored in a buttons "value property" to my controller when the button is clicked.  I am new to asp.net mvc and I am not sure what the best method is to accomplish this task.  I tried looking around the forums but didn't find anything that was clear enough.  I don't just want the answer, I want to be able to understand it.  Appreciate any tips/hints/etc.  Below is the code for my button:

```
<div class="jumbotronAll">

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {   

        @Html.Raw("<br />")
        Html.BeginForm("Index", "AllTracks");
        {
            <input type="button" value='@item.collegeOf' class="AllTracksButtons" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ListTracksByMajor", "AllTracks", new { college = item.collegeOf })'" />
        }
        @Html.Raw("<br />")
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Whats not working? Is the action method not being hit? Is the parameter of the action method null? You need to include your controller method. And why do you have this in a `form` element when you don't appear to be posting anything? Also, it would be better to use `@Html.ActionLink()`

Answer (score 0):

The code shown in the question mixes normal form posting with JavaScript redirects. Let's simplify the approach a bit:

- Create one form wrapped in `Html.BeginForm { ... }`
- Set the action of the form to an MVC controller and action that will handle your `college` parameter. From your code, it looks like the controller is `AllTracksController`, and the Action is `ListTracksByMajor`. It's not totally clear from the question, but I'm guessing your `collegeOf` parameter is a string representing the college's display name, or some similar field. If not, adjust these instructions to fit your data type.
- In the Action method signature, you will accept the input parameter that you show set in the `value` attributes of the individual buttons on the form (so if it's a string, then you would need a string input parameter).
- Then in the Action method, you will validate the input parameter as needed, then use it to look up and load whatever model you want for the "List Tracks by Major" view.
- Then serve up the "List Tracks by Major" View populated with the Model.

Below is some sample code that demonstrates these concepts. Again, I'm making some arbitrary assumptions about your use case, but this demonstrates the approach:

## Models

### ExampleCollegeModel

```
public class ExampleCollegeModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Preserving SO variable name, but note that normal convention on public 
    /// C# property is CollegeOf
    /// </summary>
    public string collegeOf { get; set; }
}
```

### ExampleTracksByMajorModel

```
/// <summary>
/// Obviously I just made this up since I don't know what your data model should look like. You 
/// may be wanting some kind of IEnumerable, etc., so change this to whatever it needs to be. 
/// </summary>
public class ExampleTracksByMajorModel
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
    public string PropertyC { get; set; }
}
```

## Controller

```
public class AllTracksController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Guessing this is the default view that shows the form in the question.
        // You would go to the DB here and get your model loaded up. I assume from 
        // your question your view is expecting an array or some-such. 
        var colleges = new ExampleCollegeModel[]
        {
            new ExampleCollegeModel() {collegeOf = "College A"},
            new ExampleCollegeModel() {collegeOf = "College B"},
            new ExampleCollegeModel() {collegeOf = "College C"}
        };

        return View(colleges);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ListTracksByMajor(string collegeButton)
    {
        // Validate the input. Note this is simple manual validation of your string input, where you are checking for whatever
        // you want. Another way to do this would be to accept an instance of a Model object that you pass in, and if your use System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation attributes on your model, you can check ModelState.IsValid
        // If the input is invalid, you could redirect back to a different Action / View, or you could provide a default value here so you can continue on your way.
        // ....

        // Now that you have valid input, go to data store and load up what yourever your proper model is for the view you're going to show. I'm guessing 
        // it's not too similar to the below contrived example :)
        // ...

        var model = new ExampleTracksByMajorModel
        {
            PropertyA = "Some values from the database",
            PropertyB = "would be loaded here.",
            PropertyC = "By the way, you selected: " + collegeButton
        };

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

## Views

### Index (for `AllTracksController` -> `Index` Action)

```
@model YourModelNameSpace.ExampleCollegeModel[]
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "All Tracks - Choose college";   
}

<div class="container">
    <h4>Example form showing all possible college choices as individual buttons.</h4>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ListTracksByMajor", "AllTracks"))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" name="collegeButton" value='@item.collegeOf' class="btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
</div>
```

### List Tracks By Major (for `AllTracksController` -> `ListTracksByMajor` Action)

```
@model YourModelNameSpace.ExampleTracksByMajorModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List Tracks By Major - Example";
}
<h2>List TracksBy Major - based on chosen college input parameter</h2>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>
                Property A
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PropertyA)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                Property B
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PropertyB)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                Property C
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PropertyC)
            </dd>

        </dl>
    </div>
</div>
```